# How do we implement a pull over menu in xcode like in email reply

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I have searched a lot to find a way to implement the most used pull over menu when I press a button in xcode for iPhone. Something like what you see when you hit the reply button in email app. You see options to Reply, Forward, Print, Cancel. I wanted to implement it exactly the same way. Is there a standard framework already available in iOS6?
Many thanks for the excellent users of stackoverflow.

Below is the screen shot that I wanted to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **UIActionSheet**
Please look at [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)